# Linux Ubuntu Cassandra keeps loading

Tags: cassandra, lagom

On Mac OSX I could start `sbt lagom:runAll` without problems, but on Linux Ubuntu the embedded Cassandra when running in develop keeps loading. Is there a way I can set some debug configuration to figure out what the problem is?

Note: I'm currently on a Windows machine and run Ubuntu in Virtualbox.

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to run `sbt runAll` -- it's weird that this sort of "hangs" in the `lagom` task, though.

Comment: I was not able to confirm this -- what happens when you `sbt clean`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to help unfortunately. I think I'll run it natively on Windows without the embedded Cassandra server.

Comment: I think that it has something to do with permissions on the shared folder. My intention was to run IntelliJ natively on Windows and do all other operations from within Virtualbox Ubuntu.